# Credential Manager Issue in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, credentials-manager

I want to use credential manager to store the password of my machine and some websites. I have tried to add Credential for website in **Generic credential** section as below :

> Internet or network address : www.gmail.com
>
> User name : My user name without @gmail.com
>
> Password : my gmail password for that account

But it is not working when I open gmail using Internet Explorer.

I have gone through below links but it didn't working :
http://www.carltheprof.com/WhatistheCredentialManager.html

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/automatic-logon-to-websites-not-working-using/a098814a-d87c-4bf2-bb3e-a4c136bf04f0

http://www.thewindowsclub.com/credential-manager-working-windows

Please suggest if I am doing anything wrong. Moreover, Can we use that password in other browser as well?

Comment: Have you tried mail.google.com or accounts.google.com instead of www.gmail.com?

Comment: @Zaroth Yes I have tried with adding mail.google.com and accounts.google.com in Generic credential. But its not working.

Comment: @Zaroth I am trying to do this from office. May be some network setting not let it happen. I will try it at home again.

Comment: @Zaroth I have try at home as well but its not working. Can you please tell me the steps that how you had achieved this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generic Credentials are for third-party applications that manage authorization separate from the credentials of the currently logged-on user. Almost any credentials that adhere to the Microsoft standard can be stored in the Generic Credentials category.

For more information see the article
[Manage network logon credentials in Microsoft Windows](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/manage-network-logon-credentials-in-microsoft-windows/).

However, the Credential Manager is not used to store all types of credentials used for connecting to Web sites. For example, most Web site credentials in Internet Explorer are rather handled by the AutoComplete feature.

For Web logons, such as for Gmail, you should use a tool that is better adapted to
the task. The free [LastPass](https://lastpass.com/) utility is one of the best password managers
for storing
logons as well as automatically doing auto-logon to websites.
It is also cross-browser.
See [this article](http://www.guidingtech.com/7444/lastpass-features-best-password-manager/) for more info.

Comment: Another point worth making is that credentials won't be sent to sites which aren't in the Intranet security zone in Internet Explorer (unless you've enabled sending credentials for other zones).

Comment: @harrymc Yes there are many password managers are available in market but my question is specific regarding credential manager. Can you please give example or elaborate more for what kind of third party application use this and what is autocomplete feature of Explorer? Where it is mentioned that credential manager is not used to store all kind of web? Because while creating credential, it states to enter website name or domain name and not any specification is given for site list.

Comment: AutoComplete and LastPass do the same thing: Remember what values you entered in [HTML forms](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) on specific pages, LastPass just does it better. This is because there is no way for IE to know where on the Gmail form to put your name/password, but it can remember values that you once entered in the fields for next time, which is what AutoComplete does. Credential Manager uses Generic Credentials more for network logons where the user/password protocol is well defined.

Comment: So it means though credential manager suggest to enter _Internet or server address_, we can't login for GMail, facebook or any other sites, correct?

Comment: And we can use credential manager **ONLY** for Network Log-ons?

Comment: Credential Manager can be used by any application to verify a logon, but the application must actively use it. A web-page is sandbagged and cannot interact with local software, and I'm not aware of any API in IE for it. For a lengthier discussion see [Windows 7: Exploring Credential Manager and Windows Vault](http://www.neowin.net/news/main/09/03/07/windows-7-exploring-credential-manager-and-windows-vault).

Comment: @harrymc The last comment and website is quite helpful. Now I understand the behavior of credential manager properly. Thanks a lot. :)